# How enable ctrl + arrow up in windows xp?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-explorer, keyboard-navigation

In windows 7 I can go to next (upper) folder level in explorer just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow up</kbd>. Is there a way to set this shortkey in windows xp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows XP Explorer allows this action: *switch to the parent folder* by pressing the  `BACKSPACE` key. See more in the [Keyboard shortcuts for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) Microsoft article